# How to connect two text box with no border in middle

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Example. 12 November  2016" />
    <input type="text"   placeholder="10:00 AM" />
</div>
```

I want to know how to connect these two text boxes with no border line in middle.

Comment: How do you want them 'connected' ? Simply placed side by side with no space between them, not even the vertical line which forms the right-hand edge of the first input and the left-hand edge of the second input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this trick :**

```css
.first {
  border : none;
  width : 30%;
}
.second {
  margin-left:-10px;
  border : none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Example. 12 November  2016" class="first"/>
    <input type="text"  placeholder="10:00 AM" class="second"/>
</div>
```